# ¿Cómo obtener el nombre de archivo en el controlador desde el JSP en un input de tipo file?

Tags: java, html, jsp, controller, multipart

No me es posible obtener el nombre del archivo de un input de tipo "file".

```
<input type="file" id="ide" class="form-control" name="filename" accept=".xlsx, .xls, .xlsm,  image/*,  image/jpg,  image/png, .doc, .docx, .pdf">
```

Esa es la parte del JSP.

```
Part arhivo = request.getPart("filename");
```

De esa manera no lo extrae. Mi idea es obtener el nombre para poder extraer su extensión y validarla si es o no correcta. Me han solicitado validarla mediante front y backend, y es en este último el problema. Espero me puedan ayudar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el tutorial [The fileupload Example Application](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/glraq.html) la documentación de Java EE 6, se encuentra este método para obtener el nombre del archivo que ha seleccionado el usuario:

```
private String getFileName(final Part part) {
    //final String partHeader = part.getHeader("content-disposition");
    //LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "Part Header = {0}", partHeader);
    for (String content : part.getHeader("content-disposition").split(";")) {
        if (content.trim().startsWith("filename")) {
            return content.substring(
                    content.indexOf('=') + 1).trim().replace("\"", "");
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

He comentado las primeras dos líneas, pues la llamada a LOGGER requiere alguna dependencia adicional.

De manera análoga y, quizás un poco más segura, podrías ver el MIME type de la parte, que puedes recuperar con:

```
archivo.getHeader("content-type");
```

Si hay un MIME type, te basas en él, y si no, ya te basas en el nombre del archivo como tal:

```
Part archivo = request.getPart("filename");
String fileName = getFileName(archivo);
String mimeType = archivo.getHeader("content-type");
```